# Exclude Specific List Items from Search

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-server, search

So I have this scenario:

1. I have a list with a column called `Status`
2. The status field is either `Open` or `Closed`

What I want to do is to only include in search results items whose status are `Open`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Where you want to include? in your view?

Comment: @AakashMorya I should have been more specific. I need to exclude them from search results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Search query Webpart for this and use filters to refine your result set. Have a look at the following link on how to configure this
[Using-content-search-web-part-and understanding SP2013 search](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on SP 2013 - Create a result source.  The query in the result source should look something like

{searchTerms} Status:"Open" ContentTypdId:0x01xxxxxxx

ContentTypeId should be the content type for your list

Configure your content search webpart or search results web part to use your new result source

Comment: I would use the path to the list instead of the content type id (as it is sometimes tricky to get this to work correctly (if the list content type is inheriting from another content type and the same column is used in another list with the same content type. So I do suggest you change the query a little bit to:

{searchTerms} Status:"Open" Path:https://site.sharepoint.com/sitename/Lists/listname